# Is retrieving a value from an array, saving in temp variable faster than just accessing the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a highly optimized program for a Raspberry Pi. 75 % of the OCed CPU (total 900 Mhz) is used already, and my code might not be the final piece.

The program needs to access the same data in an array several times in a loop. I know it is more readable to extract the value and place in a temporary variable. But does it speed up processing/reduce CPU time for lookup?

I'm compiling and building directly on the Raspberry Pi (model B) if that changes anything. The project is using a custom fork of Linux based on kernel 3.2.27. Gcc/g++ information (same results):

```
$ gcc -v
[...]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
```

Comment: Both are constant time. Is this really the bottleneck?

Comment: If your memory is uniform, then all memory is the same.

Comment: No bottleneck yet, it is still WIP, but I want to avoid bottlenecks early in the process so I don't have to weed them out in deploy stage/after code has been deployed. And it doesn't hurt to optimize code or expanding knowledge anyways.

Comment: Are you talking about a single value (which the compiler is likely to move to a register regardless of how you access it), or several ones?

Comment: @Leeor it is 2 * 20 values (presently). Not a lot, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a big huge caveat.

> No bottleneck yet, it is still WIP, but I want to avoid bottlenecks early in the process so I don't have to weed them out in deploy stage/after code has been deployed. And it doesn't hurt to optimize code or expanding knowledge anyways.

It most certainly does hurt to optimize code. What you are doing is "premature optimization". Performance certainly is a code metric, sometimes of utmost importance. However, code optimized for performance tends to reduce almost every other metric of what constitutes "good code": understandability, portability, maintainability, testability, etc. Don't optimize until you know you need to do so.

You are also asking about a small optimization here. A much bigger one: Suppose your algorithm is O(N<sup>2</sup>), and there is an O(N*log(N)) algorithm in the literature that does exactly the same thing. You can optimize that O(N<sup>2</sup>) to the state of being completely unreadable, unmaintainable, untestable and see but a tiny boost in performance. Or you could switch to that O(N*log(N)) algorithm and have clean, maintainable code.

---

That said, yes, putting things in local variables can help, but it can also hurt. Sometimes the compiler will optimize those multiple array accesses into a temporary, compiler-invented variable. If that's the case, those local variables are just noise that might well confuse the compiler and make the generated code slower.

Sometimes the compiler won't optimize away those multiple array accesses. It's when it won't optimize those accesses away is when storing the contents into a local variable helps. Don't second guess the compiler. See what it's doing.

There is another avenue to using a local variable. One of the things that will prevent the compiler from optimizing away those multiple accesses to the same array element is use of multiple pointers. The compiler doesn't know if `foo[index1]` points to the same location in memory as `bar[index2]`. Suppose you write to `bar[index2]` between accesses to `foo[index1]`. The compiler can't optimize away that second access to `foo[index1]` because the value might have changed.

What would be nice is a way to somehow promise to the compiler that nothing aliases the memory pointed to by `foo`. The C standard offers the `restrict` keyword to do just that. If this was C, you could qualify `foo` with `restrict`, thus giving the compiler the ability to optimize away those multiple accesses to `foo[index1]` into one.

One minor problem: The `restrict` keyword is not in C++ (yet). However, gcc (and also clang) offers the `__restrict__` keyword to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this will be optimized away. But remember that accessing data that is compactly stored in memory is cheaper because of processor cache.